# plain Scala Templates in Play 2.0

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

Since Intellij does not yet support the Play-Scala-Template-Engine I was thinking about using plain Scala for the time being, since having no code-completion, import help really slows my development down.

Is it possible to use **plain Scala**, not the @-ish wrapper, as a template-engine in Play 2.0? I guess that I could simply `return ok(Htmp.apply("fooo"))` from my (java) controllers and construct view-generating static methods in scala as my pseudo-templates, but I would like the overall structure of the project to similar to the "original".

To illustrate:

a normal template for my `Meetings`-Controller would be stored in

`/app/views/Meetings/list.scala.html`

and look something akin to this:

```
@(currentUser: User, meetings: Set[Meeting])

@main("Possible Meeting Dates") {
 @for(meeting <- meetings){
  "do fancy layout"
 }
}
```

I **would want** the whole thing to be stored under

`/app/views/Meetings/list.scala`

and contain something akin to this:

```
import play.api.templates._

def render(user: User, meetings:Set[Meeting]): Html = {
  Html("doing the layout here")
}
```

So my IDE gets that this is Scala and helps accordingly. Doing the latter whilst renaming the file to `list.scala.html` does not quite work: `play compile` causes some reference to be generated. I am able to call

`views.html.Meetings.list.render()`

like expected, but it does not take any parameters.

Do I need to adhere to a certain signature for the compiler-magic to work, or does this whole Idea simply not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a very personal solutions. Reported (but not liked :-( ) here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731573/how-would-you-improve-this-scala-basic-xml-template

Hope that can of an help...

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since this has been open for a while now I think what I want is not intended in Play 2.0 (yet).